trying to install gnome extension like user theme in the installation section a error comes
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'
../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 '__libc_start_call_main'
../csu/libc-start.c:360 '__libc_start_main_impl'
(null):0 '(null)'
(null):0 '(null)'


Please edit your question to include more information about your machine, such as the ubuntu version.

Please also explain what leads to those errors, what you're doing, which commands you're running etc etc

it's solve automatic after a restart .  actually form gnome extension site i click on install and the extension mannager popup after clicking install this error comes in popup

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
